# php pdo catching connection exception with custom exception handler

Tags: php, exception, pdo, custom-exceptions

What im trying to achieve here , is when the pdo connection throws an exception , my custom exception handler takes the message and passes it on so i can catch it with my custom exception handler.

```
try {
       $mysqli = new PDO('mysql:host='.THOST.';dbname='.TDB.'', TUSER, TPASS);
     }   

          catch (PDOException $e) {

              $a = $e->getMessage();
          throw new customException  ( "Failed to connect to MySQL:". $a );   
          die();
          }

         catch (customException $e){ 

                 echo  $e->errorMessage(); 
       }
```

BUT it returns this error :
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'customException' with message ......

Comment: I see no custom handler here

Comment: @YourCommonSense
I have a custom exception class , which if in development just  displays the  errors in a certain way , and when in production it will email the errors to me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in another try-catch block.

```
try {
  try {
    $mysqli = new PDO('mysql:host='.THOST.';dbname='.TDB.'', TUSER, TPASS);
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
    $a = $e->getMessage();
    throw new customException  ( "Failed to connect to MySQL:". $a );
  }
} catch(customException $e) {
  echo  $e->errorMessage();
  // Do what you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing custom exception **handler** with custom exception class. You need the former one and the other answer is wrong.

Explanation.

In your application code you have to writing **one single line only:**

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.THOST.';dbname='.TDB.'', TUSER, TPASS);
```

**without multiple tries** and stuff. Just the code you need to run.

While all the handling logic goes into [**handler**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php)

Comment: Apologies ,yes you are correct , I have a custom exception class.
The below answer works when i tried it . Please explain why it is incorrect of possible .

Comment: explained. BTW, emailing errors is a VERY BAD idea.